# Difference in `require("module");` to `require("module").function;`

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Good day, I just want to know if there's any performance issue,  advantages/disadvantages or size with regards of implementing this kind of logic in NodeJS' `require`.

Exhibit A

`const a = require('module');`

Exhibit B

`const a = require('module').function;`

Comment: These do different things. Presumably you are **using** `a.function` in Exhibit A, and `a` in Exhibit B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` in Nodejs is :

> Node.js follows the CommonJS module system, and the built-in require
>   function is the easiest way to include modules that exist in separate
>   files. The basic functionality of require is that it reads a
>   javascript file, executes the file, and then proceeds to return the
>   exports object.

So, As per what `require` do, it does not affect in the performance.

**Note :**

> When You are using core Module like `lodash` then including the direct
>   `module` its affect performance.
>
> Because You see in lodash there are different file/folder for each
>   function. So its always good practice to include only the function
>   from module which is required.

**Example :**

```
const {get, isEmpty} = require('lodash');
```

Comment: I've understand but can you refer to my comment? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736036/difference-in-requiremodule-to-requiremodule-function?noredirect=1#comment92400683_52736610

Comment: That makes sense. Aside from readability you must also consider the complexity of the module you are importing to a project. Thanks @IftekharDani

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any performance implications of the type of ***require*** you are making, the reason being to this is every time require returns/looks for a cached object in a memory.

[Official Node API Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)
[Require useful info](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8)

You should require a module as per your need like if you are using only one function from the module then you should opt

```
const a = require('module').function;
```

Else go with

```
const a = require('module');
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Sanket, but let's take it in another way, I'm only using a `single` function on that imported `module`, what would be the best approach/practice? Require `all` of the `module` or just a `single` function since I'm only using one?

Comment: @Quer Import single function only as I mentioned in my answer. It makes your code look more cleaner and avoids accidental calling/accessing the other function from the module.

Comment: Another way this can be done: `const { functionA } = require('module');` which is the same as: `const a = require('module').functionA;`